# Is there a way to block incoming IP or user agent using Openshift 3.11 default Router?

Tags: java, web-applications, openshift, wildfly, bots

We are looking for a router and rule based way to block incoming http requests in openshift, wildfly10 environment. Is there one without adding another layer like reverse proxy?

We added the following java code to avoid getting more than 500 sessions and avoid out of memory errors (code 137 POD exit) for a web App. Unwanted http requests were pounding the site continuously.

```
if((!badIP.isEmpty() && userIP.contains(badIP)) || (!badAgent.isEmpty() && reqAgent.contains(badAgent)) ){
  HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);//gets current session but will not create a new
  if(session==null){
   return;
  }
  session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1);//kill it, reduces maxsessions count. invalidate destroys but   removes after inactive time out
  return;
}
```

This solution seems to be working and the idea can be used in non java application as well. The problem seems to be a common one for web apps and would like to know of other options in Openshift environment.

Comment: IP whitelisting can be done on the route (https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/routes.html#whitelist), but UA blocking would have to be done within your application code

Comment: @WillGordon, Thanks for your comment. I was aware of the whitelisting, but no rules, so how do I use it as a blacklisting? I want to prevent some IPs coming in.

Comment: If you have the `ovs-networkpolicy` SDN plugin installed (https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/architecture/networking/sdn.html#architecture-additional-concepts-sdn), you could rely on NetworkPolicy objects for IP blacklistingc (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)